# PYTHON: overlaying netCDF data on a basemap (contourf)

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I'm new to python and to netCDF but have been working at the following issue for several days now with no progress. My code is based on various tutorials and examples I've read, and I can't figure out what is going wrong!

Essentially I want to be able to overlay a plot of some netCDF data onto a basemap. My code (in full) is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
# from scipy.io import netcdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

when = 0 # improve this variable later so that user input can be date/ time

filename = '/net/glusterfs_surft/surft/data/LakeData/JRA55/raw/jra55_tmp.1964010100_1964123121.nc' # input the complete filepath here
# open the file at the address 'filename' for reading:
fopen = Dataset(filename, 'r') # <-- turn on if using netCDF4
# fopen = netcdf.netcdf_file(filename, 'r') <-- turn on if using scipy.io

# variables in JRA-55 are:
# TMP_GDS0_HTGL
# initial_time0_hours
# initial_time0_encoded
# initial_time0
# g0_lon_2 (runs from 0 to 360E in 1.25 deg steps)
# g0_lat_1 (runs from 90 to -90 in 1.25 deg steps)

# now set variables x, y and 'data':
x = fopen.variables['g0_lon_2'][:] # this is a 1D longitude array
y = fopen.variables['g0_lat_1'][:] # this is a 1D latitude array 
data = fopen.variables['TMP_GDS0_HTGL'][:] 
# this is a 3D array with temperature saved at each point in 2D space and time
# reduce data to a 2D array for a specific time:
data_when = data[when,:,:]

#close the file at the address
fopen.close()

# create a basemap to plot onto:
m = Basemap(width=5000000, height=3500000,\
        resolution='l', projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=40, lat_0=50, lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81,20))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181,20))
# 
#   add other basemap drawing options here 
#

# convert 1D matrices into 2D fill matrices for processing:
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.contourf(xx, yy, data_when, latlon=True)

plt.show()
```

If I comment out the basemap section then my data looks like this:

[world map, no borders, temperature contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bnEI.png)

Whereas if I include them (no need to comment out the `plt.contourf(xx, yy, data_when, latlon=True)`) the image I get is:

[stereographic projection at lat = 50, lon = 0, with borders, no contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WCoe.png)

I want to be able to display the corresponding sections of these images in one plot, but don't know how. The map projection used is unimportant, but the image should correspond to both the data and the basemap.

Thanks! I hope you can help!

Comment: clearly users will not have access to the same filepath as me. if you wanted to be really helpful the data I'm using is from the JRA-55 (precisely the 1964 2m temperature), but as I expect most won't have this to hand, just any advice based on netCDF would be great!

Comment: What You are doing seems principally correct. Without original data it is indeed difficult to debug. I have been in similar situations and I suggest following control procedure: plot on larger map with full coverage, to see if any data is visible; check actual values of xx and yy and compare to map coordinates (you sould see them hovering mouse over the map); check if coordinate variables are correct; flip coordinates before/after meshgrid, etc...

Comment: You could try not using `latlon=True`.  Instead create the map indices using `xx, yy = m(xx, yy)`.  I've had that help in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The following version of my code is fully functional. Thanks to [sea_hydro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1757464/sea-hydro) for the help provided in the comments. I hope the working version of the code can be useful to other newbies who are hoping to solve this problem!

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
# from scipy.io import netcdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

when = 0 # improve this variable later so that user input can be date/ time

filename = 'some_filepath' # input the complete filepath here
# open the file at the address 'filename' for reading:
fopen = Dataset(filename, 'r') # <-- turn on if using netCDF4
# fopen = netcdf.netcdf_file(filename, 'r') <-- turn on if using scipy.io

# now set variables x, y and 'data':
x = fopen.variables['lon_var'][:] # this is a 1D longitude array
y = fopen.variables['lat_var'][:] # this is a 1D latitude array 
data = fopen.variables['data_var'][:] 
# this is a 3D array with a value saved at each point in 2D space and time
# reduce data to a 2D array for a specific time:
data_when = data[when,:,:]

#close the file at the address
fopen.close()

# create a basemap to plot onto:
m = Basemap(width=10000000, height=7000000,\
        resolution='l', projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=40, lat_0=50, lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81,20))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181,20))
# 
#   add other basemap drawing options here 
#
```

This code uses the stereographic map projection. Other basemap options can be found [in the matlpotlib basemap toolkit documentation](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapsetup.html)

```
# convert 1D matrices into 2D fill matrices for processing:
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xx, yy = m(xx, yy)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, data_when)

plt.show()
```

Additional plots can also be overlaid.

Comment: in order for the above code to work fully I've found that an extra value for the data at 360deg longitude is also necessary despite this being the same as the value for 0deg. users may also note that this code does not produce the correct results for stereographic projections (although it may look like it does at a glance). Some other basemaps work - I've had the most success with Albers.